# How to get the characters preceded by "add_"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a strings "add_dinner", "add_meeting", "add_fuel_surcharge" and I want to get characters that are preceded by "add_" (dinner, meeting, fuel_surcharge).

```
[^a][^d]{2}[^_]\w+
```

I have tried this one, but it only works for "add_dinner"

```
[^add_]\w+
```

This one works for "add_fuel_surcharge", but takes "inner" from "add_dinner"

Help me to understand please.

Comment: I'm not a regex expert so I just want to give you this handy webpage to write, test, or see other user uploaded regex'es :) http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: `var str = str.substring(str.indexOf("_")+1)` will work if there's always an _ in the string. So will str.substring(4) if there is always an add_ - ditto str.split("add_")[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions, you need to use a capturing group:

```
var myregexp = /add_(\w+)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

`[^add_]` is a character class that matches a single character except `a`, `d` or `_`. When applied to `add_dinner`, the first character it matches is `i`, and `\w+` then matches `nner`.

Answer (score 3):

Use capturing groups:

```
/^add_(\w+)$/
```

Check the returned array to see the result.

Comment: I've never heard the term "control groups" before.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Me neither. Corrected. (Myth busters in the background :X)

Answer (score 0):

The `[^...]` construct matches any single character except the ones listed. So `[^add_]` matches any single character other than "a", "d" or "_".

If you want to retrieve the bit after the `_` you can do this:

```
/add_(\w+_)/
```

Where the parentheses "capture" the part of the expression inside. So to get the actual text from a string:

```
var s = "add_meeting";
var result = s.match(/add_(\w+)/)[1];
```

This assumes the string will match such that you can directly get the second element in the returned array that will be the "meeting" part that matched `(\w+)`.

If there's a possibility that you'll be testing a string that won't match you need to test that the result of `match()` is not null.

(Or, possibly easier to understand: `result = "add_meeting".split("_")[1];`)

Comment: Or better split on add_ in case there are more than one _

Comment: Thanks for asnwer, now I see the way I should go with regex:)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter `_` string by `JavaScript for loop` ,

```
var str = ['add_dinner', 'add_meeting', 'add_fuel_surcharge'];
var filterString = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++){
        if(str[i].indexOf("_")>-1){
            filterString.push(str[i].substring(str[i].indexOf("_") + 1, str[i].length));
        }
    }
alert(filterString.join(", "));
```